# Reading TYPOscript fe_users does not work within a COA

Tags: mysql, typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I have just the following problem, I would like to spend via TYPOScript a specific FE_user in the template, only this does not work, is there a restiktives SQL statement or I use here what wrong? Maybe it's the nesting?

Here is the code:

```
lib.contactPasswords = COA
lib.contactPasswords.10 = TEXT
lib.contactPasswords.10.value (
    <p>User: Safari</p>
)
lib.contactPasswords.20 = CONTENT
lib.contactPasswords.20 {
    table = fe_users
    select {
        max = 1
        pidInList = 173
        andWhere = username = 'Safari'
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj
    {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = username
        wrap =|<br / >
    }
}
lib.contactPasswords.20.wrap = <div>User: |</div>
```

And the output is the same like:

```
<p>User: Safari</p>
<div>User:</div>
```

Desired result:

```
<p>User: Safari</p>
<div>User: Safari</div>
```

Can someone explain to me where the mistake is, why the content remains empty?

*More Information:*

- TYPO3 Version: 8.7.19
- Using like: `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.contactPasswords" />` in Fluid Template
- And yes: The User "Safari" exist in the database :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the username is `Safari`? Usernames are usually all lowercase in TYPO3. If you added it through the backend it will be cast to lowercase. So it would be `safari`.

You should not have an enter between `cObject` and `{`. It should be `cObject {`

Also `andWhere` is deprecated since TYPO3 7.1 and removed in TYPO3 8.7. You should use `where` instead.

For me, this works:

```
lib.contactPasswords.20 = CONTENT
lib.contactPasswords.20 {
  table = fe_users
  select {
    max = 1
    pidInList = 173
    where = username = 'safari'
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = username
    wrap = |<br / >
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and that with the andWhere also seems to have been part of the problem, but the andWhere was just a desperate test that I had forgotten to undo before the post. Exactly so with the username, I have changed for the post, in reality it is different and is also written in small letters. But the error was in a very different place, my IDE has moved the parenthesis after the "renderObj" in the next line 6, thus the TS was broken.

Answer (score 0):

'andWhere' reqires, that you also used 'where' in your statement.
But avoid using 'andWhere' since it is deprecated. See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/7.1/Deprecation-25112-andWhere.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and that with the andWhere also seems to have been part of the problem, but the andWhere was just a desperate test that I had forgotten to undo before the post. Sry but the real problem was the braclet after renderObj in the new line :(